# Declared variable outside function, cant use it now

Tags: javascript

```
var date;
document.getElementById("myButton1").onclick = function(){
    date = document.getElementById("myText1").value;   
   
}
console.log(date);
```

Why does this code not work? I'm new to js and i cant find the answer anywhere.

Comment: What you expect the code to do?

Comment: Lines of code in JavaScript don't necessarily run sequentially. The `console.log()` statement will run immediately after the `var date;` line. The `onclick` function won't run until/unless the `myButton1` element gets clicked. So, you are trying to log an uninitialized variable with your code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did click the button

Comment: @Teemu to display the text which i have input in the console

Comment: Then just put `console.log()` inside the click handler function.

Comment: For now console.log is launched immediately with unassigned value, if you want to console.log date with newly assigned value, you should move it inside function at the end

Comment: @ScottMarcus So what do you suggest i do to make the onclick run first?

Comment: But the `console.log()` will run before you click the button. So, later, when you do click the button, the `date` variable will take on a value, but that's all that will happen. Move the `console.log()` line so that it is *inside* of the function *after* `date` has been initialized.

Comment: @Jacki I need the variable for some arithmetic later

Comment: That's not a problem. The code is technically fine. It's just that your expecting `date` to have a value that can be logged prior to `date` getting initialized.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You see i need to use the "date" outside the function for later.

Comment: You seem to be failing to understand what you're being told. Move the console.log line into the click handler. Your date variable will be accessible the way you have it now since you declared it outside the handler

Comment: @j08691 I have two more such variables, "month" and "year".
I want to do the exact same thing that i have done here to them as well and later use all these values for some arithmetic
If i move the console.log inside the click handler, i can't access it from outside, where i need to use it.

Comment: You can. So either you're explaining your situation incorrectly or what you've posted is incomplete

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `console.log(date)` inside the function and it will work.
Like this:

```
var date;
document.getElementById("myButton1").onclick = function(){
    date = document.getElementById("myText1").value;   
    console.log(date)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your `console.log()` statement is executing prior to the `onclick` callback function (which sets the value of `date`). A "callback" function is a function that will be called at some point **later** (if at all) so your JavaScript code doesn't run sequentially, line by line.

Your code requires that the button be clicked in order for `date` to be initialized, so you can't expect `date` to have a value until *after* you click the button, but  your `console.log()` is running immediately, before `date` gets a value.

Here's what you should do:

```js
// Get your reference to the element(s) you know you'll need to 
// work with just once and don't set your variable equal to a 
// property value of the element - set it to the element itself.
// That way, if you ever decide you want a different property
// value, you already have the element reference and don't have
// to scan the document for the same element again.
const date = document.getElementById("myText1"); ;

// This line sets up an "event handling callback function" for
// the date element. The function's code will only run if/when the 
// element gets its value changed and loses the focus. By setting up 
// the event handler on the change event, you can be assured that
// the variable will always have the most up to date value

// Also, avoid event "propeties" like onclick
// as they are an older way to set up events and are not as robust
// as the modern standard way of using .addEventListener().
date.addEventListener("change", function(){  
    // The following line will only run if/when the button is clicked.
    // If that happens before a date is specified in the myText1 
    // element, there won't be a value.
    console.log(date.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myText1">
```